# Using foverlaps to truncate episodes

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to use `data.table::foverlaps()` to generate new data tables. In one application, I would like to use foverlaps to identify gaps and then use this information to truncate my original data table.

Suppose that I have a dataset (`df1`) of 2 employees (`id`) at a company with date ranges (`start_date` and `end_date`) for the periods in which they work on different projects
(`proj_id`; either "A", "B" or "C").

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
df1<-data.table(id = rep(1:2,each=3),
           start_date = ymd(c("1998-04-03","1999-03-08","2000-08-13",
                              "2005-03-03","2007-10-12","2014-02-23")),
           end_date = ymd(c("1999-03-07","2000-08-12","2021-04-23",
                            "2007-09-05","2014-02-22","2019-05-04")),
           proj_id = c("A","B","A","B","C","A"))

> df1
   id start_date   end_date proj_id
1:  1 1998-04-03 1999-03-07       A
2:  1 1999-03-08 2000-08-12       B
3:  1 2000-08-13 2021-04-23       A
4:  2 2005-03-03 2007-09-05       B
5:  2 2007-10-12 2014-02-22       C
6:  2 2014-02-23 2019-05-04       A
```

Now I have another dataset (`df2`) that specifies the time that I want to truncate from `df1`.

```
df2 <- data.table(id = 1:2,
                  start_date = ymd("1998-07-20", "2006-06-12"),
                  end_date = ymd("1998-08-15", "2016-04-08"))

> df2
   id start_date   end_date
1:  1 1998-07-20 1998-08-15
2:  2 2006-06-12 2016-04-08
```

I can then use `data.table::foverlaps()` to identify the overlapping episodes:

```
> setkey(df1,id,start_date,end_date)
> foverlaps(df2, df1, type="any", 
+           by.x=c("id","start_date","end_date"))
   id start_date   end_date proj_id i.start_date i.end_date
1:  1 1998-04-03 1999-03-07       A   1998-07-20 1998-08-15
2:  2 2005-03-03 2007-09-05       B   2006-06-12 2016-04-08
3:  2 2007-10-12 2014-02-22       C   2006-06-12 2016-04-08
4:  2 2014-02-23 2019-05-04       A   2006-06-12 2016-04-08
```

I would now like to use this data to generate a new version of `df1`, where I generate new episodes by truncating the gaps identified above. My desired DT is therefore:

````
  id start_date   end_date proj_id
1:  1 1998-04-03 1998-07-19       A
2:  1 1998-08-16 1999-03-07       A
3:  1 1999-03-08 2000-08-12       B
4:  1 2000-08-13 2021-04-23       A
5:  2 2005-03-03 2006-06-11       B
6:  2 2016-04-09 2019-05-04       A
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be alternatives that work better, but this could work based on your `foverlaps` result.

Assume you created another data.table called `df3` with your `foverlaps` result:

```
df3 <- foverlaps(df2, df1, type = "any", by.x = c("id", "start_date", "end_date"))
```

Then you could iterate through each row, and add 0, 1, or 2 date ranges depending on overlap (truncate at end, or beginning, or entire range is blocked out).

```
dt <- data.table(start_date = Date(), end_date = Date(), id = numeric(), proj_id = numeric())

for (i in seq_len(nrow(df3))) {
  if (df3$start_date[i] < df3$i.start_date[i]) {
    dt <- rbind(dt, data.table(start_date = df3$start_date[i], end_date = df3$i.start_date[i] - 1, id = df3$id[i], proj_id = df3$proj_id[i]))
  } 
  if (df3$end_date[i] > df3$i.end_date[i]) {
    dt <- rbind(dt, data.table(start_date = df3$i.end_date[i] + 1, end_date = df3$end_date[i], id = df3$id[i], proj_id = df3$proj_id[i]))
  }
}
```

Finally, you can remove the `foverlaps` results from your initial `df1` since new ranges have been determine for those (using `fsetdiff`). Then, you can add the new ranges back.

```
rbind(fsetdiff(df1, df3[,1:4]), dt)[order(id, start_date)]
```

**Output**

```
   id start_date   end_date proj_id
1:  1 1998-04-03 1998-07-19       A
2:  1 1998-08-16 1999-03-07       A
3:  1 1999-03-08 2000-08-12       B
4:  1 2000-08-13 2021-04-23       A
5:  2 2005-03-03 2006-06-11       B
6:  2 2016-04-09 2019-05-04       A
```